# Differentiate with respect to X

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having trouble with the below question on how to differentiate with respect to $x$.

$\sqrt{x^3}$

Which index law would I use for this?

Thanks

Comment: Convert it to the form $x^\alpha$ and use the power rule.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{x^3} = x^{\frac{3}{2}}$

So $\frac{dy}{dx}$  $x^\frac{3}{2} = \frac{3}{2}x^{\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{3\sqrt{x}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

It is equal to $x^{3/2}$ thus $y'=1.5x^{1/2}$